# php xml get element use attribute value

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am new in php.

I want to parse emp_test.xml from url like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>
```

To get all img has attribute is john:

```
$url = 'https://.../emp_test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->xpath("//*[@emp_name='john']/img") as $node)
{
    $img = (string) $node;
    return $img;
}
```

I can parse xml.

But, this is reult:

```
john_1.jpg
```

How to get all img has attribute is john like?

```
john_1.jpg
john_2.jpg
john_3.jpg
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try using $img .= $node inside foreach

Comment: @GabrielChiHongLee: Still like that. Only john_1.jpg is show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this.

```
            <?php
    $url = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <all_emp>
    <emp_detail>
        <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
        <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
        <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
        <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
        <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
        <emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
    </emp_detail>
    </all_emp>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $imgstring ='';
    foreach ($xml->emp_detail->emp as $node)
    {     
        if (strpos((string) $node->img, 'john') !== false) {
          $imgstring .= (string) $node->img.",";
        }


    }

    print_r($imgstring);
?>
```

Comment: I follow your code. In foreach loop, after "$img = (string) $node->emp->img;", i add "return $img;". But, when i change emp_name is john, marry, david , or any string , it always show john_1.jpg. Does i miss something?

Comment: you are return in first iteration. so it will return first one. got it?

Comment: you have to concatinate in loop. then outside the for loop you should return

Comment: Still like that. And, when i change emp_name is john, marry, david , or any string , it always show john_1.jpg.

Comment: is this you want?

Comment: No. I want get all img with attribute is john. That mean, get john_1.jpg, john_2.jpg, john_3.jpg.

Comment: Oh, no. I just want john_1.jpg, john_2.jpg, john_3.jpg.

Comment: I glad for your help. But my question is "how to get all img has attribute is john ?" That mean i just want get john_1.jpg, john_2.jpg, john_3.jpg. Not all of it.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are my idol.

Comment: glad to help you